# JAR file not running when adding images

Tags: java, jar, bufferedimage

I was having problems exporting the pictures into the JAR file and after some browsing i found some sollution, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
try {
        //leftFoot = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/leftFoot.png"));
        //rightFoot = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/rightFoot.png"));
        URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/leftFoot.png");  
          leftFoot = ImageIO.read(url);  
          url = this.getClass().getResource("/resources/rightFoot.png");  
          rightFoot = ImageIO.read(url);  


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

So, if i try to upload the items from the first two lines(and comment the following 4), the main GUI stuff runs in the JAR file but the images ar not shown. If i do it the other way round(the code above), no GUI element works in the jar file. I have a "resources" folder containing the pictures both in the "bin" folder and in the main folder along bin,src,settings etc. cause i read somewhere that this is how it supposed to be, although i do not know why. leftFoot and rightFoot are BufferedImage objects. Could you tell me what is not working here?

Comment: After you have the URL object, try printing out the absolute path of it. Your relative paths are probably not the actual relative path needed to reference the images relatively from this.getClass().

Comment: Also, I would expand the Jar in a temp directory and check which are its actual contents. Most probably, the images are in the base directory of the classpath or not even inside the Jar at all.